# Airflow docker, _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS argument, why there is a comment to not use that arg in production?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

Is there a reason that Airflow has put this comment after version 2.5.2 till 2.6.1 info their compose files?

```
# WARNING: Use _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS option ONLY for a quick checks
        # for other purpose (development, test and especially production usage) build/extend Airflow image.
```

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.5.2/docker-compose.yaml

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.6.1/docker-compose.yaml

There is nothing in official documentation about it.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added this description because if users use this variable then it usually make:

- *installation longer*, need to be done on every single container
- *non-reproducible*, today everything work fine, but after user restarts container it more likely get new dependencies
- *break dependencies*, at the first glance it is very handy when you tried to upgrade airflow to newer version, and usually it is end up with breaking dependencies and `pip` try to [resolve conflicts](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/dependency-resolution/) into different containers simultaneously

For some unknown reason it's quite common to use it, at least I saw a lot of issues/discussions in early 2023, where main reason was `_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS`.

So I've extended this comment which are merged in documentation of Airflow 2.5.2. In additional couple lines above also exists target solution

```
# _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS - Additional PIP requirements to add when starting all containers.
#                                Use this option ONLY for quick checks. Installing requirements at container
#                                startup is done EVERY TIME the service is started.
#                                A better way is to build a custom image or extend the official image
#                                as described in https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html.
#                                Default: ''
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly security reasons, see this [discussion](https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/24809) in airflow official github